# Выбор местоимения

Tags: грамотная-речь, словосочетания, местоимения

В ответ на сообщение о дне рождения написал "оно".
Возможно ли именно так употреблять в таком контексте?

> — Поздравляю тебя с днем рождения, у тебя сегодня же день рождения?
> — Да, **оно** сегодня.

Answer (score 1):

Я бы написала так:
*— Поздравляю тебя с днем рождения. У тебя же сегодня день рождения?

— Да, **он** сегодня.*

*День* (чего?) *рождения* — именное беспредложное словосочетание (сущ. + сущ., связь — управление), в котором главным является слово "день" (именно от него задается вопрос).
День — это слово мужского рода, поэтому при его замене используется местоимение мужского, а не среднего рода (*он*).

Из книги Юлии Шиловой "Азарт охоты, или Трофеи моей любви":
*— Я хочу иметь **свой** день рождения, как у других.

— А давай **он** будет завтра?*

[Виды связей в словосочетаниях](https://skysmart.ru/articles/russian/vidy-svyazi-v-slovosochetaniyah)

Answer (score 0):

Разница в следующем:

> — Поздравляю тебя с днем рождения, у тебя сегодня же день рождени**я**?
>
> — Да, **он** сегодня.

но:

> — Поздравляю тебя с днем-рождением, у тебя сегодня же день-рождени**е**?
>
> — Да, **оно** сегодня.